# MVC WebGrid Paging not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging, webgrid

I have a WebGrid in a Partial Page, and the Partial Page is called from the Controller inside another page, everything is working fine, except for the paging. When I try to go to next page records, it reverts back to the main page, without the Webgrid.

My Controller Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StatisticsHistory(FormCollection fc)
    {
List<StatisticsHistoryData> hisData = new List<StatisticsHistoryData>();
........

if (hisData != null)
        {
hisData = StatisticsHistoryMethods.HistoryDetailsBetweenDates(fromDate, toDate, environmentId);
                    return PartialView("_StatusHistoryGrid", hisData);
}

else
        {

        }

        return StatisticsHistory();

    }
```

My Webgrid in the Partial Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppFabricAdmin.Models.StatisticsHistoryData>

@{var Grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage:true, rowsPerPage:2, canSort: true); 
}
@{
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{



@Grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", headerStyle: "header", alternatingRowStyle: "alt",    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: Grid.Columns(Grid.Column("Environment", format: @<b>@item.Environment</b>, style: "AIDColumn"),
                                Grid.Column("Initial Status", format: @<b>@item.InitialStatus</b>, style: "FirstNameColumn"),
                                Grid.Column("Final Status", format: @<b>@item.FinalStatus</b>, style: "LastNameColumn"),
                                Grid.Column("Action Taken", format: @<b>@item.ActionTaken</b>, style: "EmailIDColumn"),
                                        Grid.Column("Comments", format: @<b>@item.Comments</b>, style: "EmailIDColumn"),
                                                Grid.Column("Time Stamp", format: @<b>@item.TimeStamp</b>, style: "EmailIDColumn")
                                                ))



}

else
{ 
<p>
    No records found.</p>
}
```

I have also tried using @using (Ajax.BeginForm()) in the main page and hv also tried using ajaxUpdateContainerId:"grid" in the Grid, but nothing works. Pls help.